# Traverse a tree and print each node and its position

Tags: tree, binary-tree, traversal

I know already how to traverse a binary tree (inorder, postorder and so on) However the problem I have is to traverse a tree and print its node and their position. This means for each node I have to print its key and position. How can I actually implement an algorithm that does this stuff? (in Java or pseudocode)

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: You'll need recoursion. Sorry.

Comment: Why would he need recursion? Simply before, after, or in between the jump to another node place a System.out.printl command with the key and position as a parameter.

Comment: what do you mean by position?

Comment: @Jim Actually the position of each node in the tree: that's the problem. In fact, the node does not have a variable position (each Node contains two pointers (Nodes): left and right and a value key). I have to deduce this in some way, considering the structure of the binary tree.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, I have written above the explanarion

Comment: So assuming the top of the tree is 'top' then you record your present position by noting where you are going.  Are there any constraints on how the position is represented.  For example, you could say TopLLL to mean the node you are at when you take 3 successive 'lefts' from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a recursive traversal method (preorder depth-first search)

```
void TraverseTree(Node node)
{
    System.out.println("Key: " + node.Key); // print key
    System.out.println("Position: " + node.Position); // print position
    System.out.println(); // print empty row

    TraverseTree(node.Left);
    TraverseTree(node.Right);
}
```

And you start it by calling:

```
TraverseTree(root);
```

The output will be ordered according to the method you choose to traverse the tree - depth-first preorder, inorder, postorder ir breath-first.

The key always has to be somewhere at the Node, you could count the position by extending the method above like that:

```
void TraverseTree(Node node, int position)
{
    System.out.println("Key: " + node.Key);
    System.out.println("Position: " + position); // different position print
    System.out.println();

    TraverseTree(node.Left, position + 1);  // different calls
    TraverseTree(node.Right, position + 1);
}
```

And start the traversal by calling it like that:

```
TraverseTree(root, 0); // counting position from 0
TraverseTree(root, 1); // counting position from 1
```

The position then again depends on how you traverse the tree.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. If `position` is inside every node, what's the big deal?

Comment: I added something more, maybe this will help him